# Windows iot/apps Programmatic Bluetooth Pairing

Tags: c#, bluetooth, raspberry-pi2, windows-10-iot-core, pairing

I'm trying to broadcast a bluetooth signal from a Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows Iot Core so that I can connect to it from smartphones and other devices, but I've been stuck for the last couple days on actually receiving a pairing signal.

Using the [Windows Bluetooth docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt270289.aspx) I am able to broadcast the signal and I can see it from my desktop as well as from my phone.
However, this is as far as I can get. I want to be able to pair without a PIN (the device will not have a screen), but the pairing fails any time the device is selected.

I am using

```
SocketProtectionLevel.BluetoothEncryptionAllowNullAuthentication
```

and

```
DevicePairingKinds.None
```

But the connection callback is never hit. I have looked at many similar questions that are either unanswered or do not have the appropriate information since I am using an RPI2 and not a desktop app.

I am not looking to pair via the web interface, but simply through code

.

[UPDATE]

I've tried the [32feet.NET](http://32feet.codeplex.com/) library but it appears to be too old to support the PI2.
I also tried a few NuGet packages, nothing seems to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not master in IoT but recently, I have started exploring it so I know Raspberry Pi 2 is hardware and we can use it to develop some basic IoT device/concepts. I can not help you with the code but may be with some idea.

I remember, for making any embedded system, we used serial port of pc and transferred command to devices. Something similar I found in one of the tutorial from David Jones. It is about to connect Bluetooth to windows 10 using serial port.

In both the explanations, SPP (Serial Port Profile) is used and also Universal Windows App is referenced. May be you get some start point or spark to comlete you work.

Check [this](https://www.hackster.io/DavidJones/generic-serial-bluetooth-with-win-10-iot-core-rpi2-fcc4ca) and [this](http://embedded101.com/Blogs/David-Jones/entryid/707/Win-10-Iot-Core-Bluetooth-Universal-Windows-Serial-App-). It also uses RPi 2.